# Как добиться асинхронности?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть функция:

```
getSome() {
   this.http.get('/some')
      .subscribe( (data: Array<object>)=> {
        console.log(data)
        this.AllMaterial = data; // не делает запрос
      }, err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
}
```

Я должен вызвать ее после проверки в другой функции:

```
second() {
    if (this.isEmpty(this.AllMaterial)) {
      this.getSome();
    }
console.log(this.AllMaterial)
}
```

При вызове естественно в косоли:
undefined => console.log(this.AllMaterial)
somedate => console.log(data)

Как сделать эту конструкцию асинхронной?

Answer (score 0):

Эта конструкция и так асинхронная.

Если не прибегать к использованию операторов RxJS - потоки можно конвертировать в `Promise` и работать уже с `async/await`:

```
getSome() {
  return this.http.get('/some').toPromise();
}

async second() {
  if (this.isEmpty(this.allMaterial)) {
    this.allMaterial = await this.getSome();
  }

  console.log(this.allMaterial);
}
```

Без `async/await`:

```
import { iif, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getSome() {
  return this.http.get('/some').pipe(
    tap((allMaterial) => {
      this.allMaterial = allMaterial;
    })
  );
}

second() {
  iif(
    () => this.isEmpty(this.allMaterial),
    this.getSome(),
    of(null)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.allMaterial);
  });
}
```

P.S. - мне вариант с `async/await` нравится больше.